# Wrap text in PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm using PIL to draw text on an image. How would I wrap a string of text. This is my code:

```
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

image = Image.open("/tmp/background-image.jpg")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf"), 50, encoding='unic')
draw.text((100, 100), text, font=font, fill="#aa0000")
image.save("/tmp/image.jpg")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python PIL draw multiline text on image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698231/python-pil-draw-multiline-text-on-image)

Comment: Import textwrap standard library and just replace "text" with "textwrap.fill(text)" on your sixth line, and it's done dynamically.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You will need to first split the text into lines of the right length, and then draw each line individually.

The second part is easy, but the first part may be quite tricky to do accurately if varible-width fonts are used. If fixed-width fonts are used, or if accuracy doesn't matter that much, then you can just use the [textwrap](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html#module-textwrap) module to split the text into lines of a given character width:

```
margin = offset = 40
for line in textwrap.wrap(text, width=40):
    draw.text((margin, offset), line, font=font, fill="#aa0000")
    offset += font.getsize(line)[1]
```

Comment: This is splitting by number of characters, not actual width - ie to fit on an image

Comment: If someone's still reading this in 2018, you can use `"\n".join(text)` instead of iterating over it and creating offsets.

Comment: @Curtwagner1984 like this `"\n".join(textwrap.wrap(text, width=40))` and next draw text.

Comment: I think this should not be the best answer, since it works only with monospace fonts

Answer (score 10):

The accepted solution wraps text basing on the fixed limit of 40 characters per line, not taking into account the box width (in pixels) nor font size. This may easily lead to underfill or overfill.

Here is a better solution - a simple code snippet to wrap text taking into account font-based width measurement:
https://gist.github.com/turicas/1455973

Answer (score 9):

Well, you can do this manually, of course, using the \n every time you want to wrap the text. It isn't the best way if you have different string everytime but gives entire control over the result.
But there is also the textwrap module.
You can use it this way:

```
import textwrap
texto = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
novo = textwrap.wrap(texto, width=20)
print(novo)
```

Results:

```
>>> 
['Lorem ipsum dolor', 'sit amet,', 'consectetur', 'adipisicing elit,', 'sed do eiusmod', 'tempor incididunt ut', 'labore et dolore', 'magna aliqua. Ut', 'enim ad minim', 'veniam, quis nostrud', 'exercitation ullamco', 'laboris nisi ut', 'aliquip ex ea', 'commodo consequat.', 'Duis aute irure', 'dolor in', 'reprehenderit in', 'voluptate velit esse', 'cillum dolore eu', 'fugiat nulla', 'pariatur. Excepteur', 'sint occaecat', 'cupidatat non', 'proident, sunt in', 'culpa qui officia', 'deserunt mollit anim', 'id est laborum.']
```

Returns a list of terms on the previous string wrapped according to the width you determinated.

Answer (score 9):

Aim for simple and consistent behavior. The `textwrap` module, as noted in other answers, only handles fixed-width fonts correctly (it is therefore not a consistent solution). Here is a simple function to wrap your text without breaking words, and it works with variable-width fonts.

```
from PIL import ImageFont


def get_wrapped_text(text: str, font: ImageFont.ImageFont,
                     line_length: int):
        lines = ['']
        for word in text.split():
            line = f'{lines[-1]} {word}'.strip()
            if font.getlength(line) <= line_length:
                lines[-1] = line
            else:
                lines.append(word)
        return '\n'.join(lines)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 12)
    text = 'An example line of text that will need to be wrapped.'
    wrapped_text = get_wrapped_text(text, font, line_length=70)
    # wrapped_text is 'An example\nline of text\nthat will\nneed to be\nwrapped.'
```

Comment: Good idea, unlucky the code is broken and you need to use `font.getlength(line)` instead of `font.getlength(text)`

Comment: @drizzt Good catch, I've updated to correct the bug.

Comment: To respect pre-existing newlines, use `text.split(' ')`

Comment: @GiacomoLacava Careful with that implementation... ignores other whitespace characters, such as tabs `'\t'`. You'll need to split first on new lines, then split on words in each line.

Comment: To fix the code from deleting newlines in the original text, you can wrap it like this:
`def get_wrapped_text_nlfix(text: str, font: ImageFont.ImageFont, line_length: int):`
    `return "\n".join([get_wrapped_text(line, font, line_length) for line in text.splitlines()])`

Answer (score 4):

Use textwrap. It works without breaking the words.

```
import textwrap
from PIL import *
caption = "Obama warns far-left candidates says average American does not want to tear down the system"

wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=50) 
word_list = wrapper.wrap(text=caption) 
caption_new = ''
for ii in word_list[:-1]:
    caption_new = caption_new + ii + '\n'
caption_new += word_list[-1]

image = Image.open('obama.jpg')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

# Download the Font and Replace the font with the font file. 
font = ImageFont.truetype(text_font, size=font_size)
w,h = draw.textsize(caption_new, font=font)
W,H = image.size
x,y = 0.5*(W-w),0.90*H-h

image.save('output.png')
```

Input Image
[image]

Output Image

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I didn't much like the idea of using yet another module to achieve this; I wanted to make it work with just the utilities in PIL. This works in Python 3.7.

I wrote this function that just wraps text based on pixel width and then checks pixel height too - if there are words it cannot fit, it cuts them off and adds ellipses to show omission (in a way that doesn't break the limits):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

def text_wrap(text,font,writing,max_width,max_height):
    lines = [[]]
    words = text.split()
    for word in words:
        # try putting this word in last line then measure
        lines[-1].append(word)
        (w,h) = writing.multiline_textsize('\n'.join([' '.join(line) for line in lines]), font=font)
        if w > max_width: # too wide
            # take it back out, put it on the next line, then measure again
            lines.append([lines[-1].pop()])
            (w,h) = writing.multiline_textsize('\n'.join([' '.join(line) for line in lines]), font=font)
            if h > max_height: # too high now, cannot fit this word in, so take out - add ellipses
                lines.pop()
                # try adding ellipses to last word fitting (i.e. without a space)
                lines[-1][-1] += '...'
                # keep checking that this doesn't make the textbox too wide, 
                # if so, cycle through previous words until the ellipses can fit
                while writing.multiline_textsize('\n'.join([' '.join(line) for line in lines]),font=font)[0] > max_width:
                    lines[-1].pop()
                    if lines[-1]:
                        lines[-1][-1] += '...'
                    else:
                        lines[-1].append('...')
                break
    return '\n'.join([' '.join(line) for line in lines])
```

Usage:

```
bg = Image.open('external/my_background.png')
ws = Image.open('external/my_overlay_with_alpha.png')

writing = ImageDraw.Draw(bg)

title = "My Title"
description = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."


title_font = ImageFont.truetype("Arial Black.ttf", size=42)
desc_font = ImageFont.truetype("Arial Narrow Italic.ttf", size=16)

description_wrapped = text_wrap(description,desc_font,writing,160,124)

# write title and description
writing.text((20,5),title,font=title_font)
writing.text((140,120),description_wrapped,font=desc_font)

out = Image.alpha_composite(bg,ws)
out.save('mysubfolder/output.png')

out.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I note though that this breaks when the bounding box is too narrow for a single word. I replaced the inner while loop with:
lines[-1].pop()
if lines[-1]:
    lines[-1][-1] += '...'
else:
    lines[-1].append('...')

Answer (score 1):

```
def img_draw(img_name,tag_line):
    
    img = Image.open(img_name)
    Width_img =img.size
    print(Width_img[0]*0.07)

    wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=int(Width_img[0]*0.07))
    word_list = wrapper.wrap(text=tag_line)

    print(word_list)

    caption_new = ""

    for ii in word_list:
        caption_new = caption_new+ ii + '\n'

    print(caption_new)

    img2 = Image.open(img_name)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img2)
    fnt = ImageFont.truetype("comicbd.ttf" , 25)
    
    draw.text((60,img.size[1]/1.5),caption_new ,font = fnt ,fill=(255, 0, 0))
    img2.save(img_name)
```

Comment: please try not to post code only answers. Try to include an explanation of what your solution does