# How to set appropriate line width for drawing text in Python PIL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am trying to draw text using PIL into an image with arbitrary resolution. My current code is a result of consulting the following two questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257147/wrap-text-in-pil) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698231/python-pil-draw-multiline-text-on-image). In both of these answers, the width value for `textwrap.wrap` was set as such: `width=40`. However, with arbitrarily changing parameters `size_x` and `size_y` this results in overfitting or underfitting the scope of image. Ideally, I would need a way to convert the size of the font into height and width pixel values in PIL but I am unsure how to do it. Here is the code as I have it now:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw 
import textwrap

size_x = 946 #This value can arbitrarily change
size_y = 300 #This value can arbitrarily change
font_size = 16 #This value can be adjusted to fit parameters of image if necessary

my_text = ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam scelerisque sapien convallis nisl facilisis, sed facilisis odio accumsan. Maecenas vel leo eu turpis porta dictum at vel neque. Donec sagittis felis non tellus lacinia facilisis. Vivamus vel nisi ullamcorper, feugiat lorem sagittis, pellentesque dolor. Curabitur est magna, feugiat ut nibh quis, blandit vestibulum nisl. Sed pulvinar condimentum purus et rutrum. Proin magna arcu, scelerisque at gravida ut, convallis quis orci. Mauris ipsum tortor, laoreet et leo ac, lacinia euismod tellus. Curabitur volutpat nisi a metus faucibus, vel iaculis nisl fermentum. Curabitur et orci id sapien porttitor dignissim at ac dolor. Donec nec mattis nisi. ']

tx = Image.new('RGB', (size_x, size_y),color=(255,255,255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(tx)

my_font = ImageFont.truetype('/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf',size=font_size)
lines = textwrap.wrap(my_text[0], width = 130) #This width value needs to be set automatically
y_text = 0
for line in lines:
    width, height = my_font.getsize(line)
    draw.text((0, y_text), line, font = my_font, fill = (0,0,0))
    y_text += height

tx.show()
```

Example image with `width=130` which is filling fairly well.

[image: width = 130]

Example image with `width=200` which is overfilling.

[image: width = 200]

Comment: The width argument means the max number of characters in a line. I don't know what you mean by "arbitrary dimensions", but if you mean arbitrary resolution then this parameter can stay constant (font gets bigger, but so does the bounding box).

Comment: @Adam I have updated the question so that it is more evident what I mean. Since width parameters is the number of characters, given particular font size and resolution it can result in overfilling of the image. I would like to find out how many characters I can use given image resolution and font size in order for my text not being out of bounds of the image.

Comment: You misunderstood the meaning of "resolution". That means same dimensions but more pixels. I.e. higher DPI (what Apple alls "retina"). In that case, the characters will have to be wrapped at the same character no matter what the resolution, so you can always use the same `width` (if you can't, then your scaling of font size is broken). Are you saying that your width and height can be changed independently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PIL's `textwrap.wrap()`'s takes a `width` which specifies the maximum number of *characters* in a line. In my opinion this is poor library design, as it's more useful to specify a maximum number of *pixels*, or *inches*. This matters because you probably have a bounding box in pixels, and variable-width fonts mean that a character count is somewhat useless.

One option is to use a fixed-width font. Then the character count is a simple division.

Another is to search for the maximum `width` that does not overflow your box. I'd set this up like a binary search, `start=1`, `end=len(string)`. `pivot=(end+start)/2`.
Do the wrapping with `width=pivot`, then find the `max(font.getsize(line) for line in wrapping)`.

- If that `max` is bigger than the bounding box, recurse left. (`end=pivot`)
- Else, repeat for `width=pivot+1`. If that overflows, you found your maximum `width`.
- If it doesn't, recurse right. (`start=pivot`)

This isn't optimal in general because individual lines might need different wrapping widths (and hence why I think this API is terrible), but if you're doing paragraphs then it should be pretty decent.

Comment: I completely agree that specifying `width` in characters is a poor design. Also thanks a lot for providing detail on both approaches (monospaced and variable-width fonts).

Comment: @MarkRansom ha, with a post about fonts I wish I could claim it was intentional :P

Comment: Just to note that `textwrap` is a Python built-in library, not part of the Python Imaging Library (PIL). `textwrap` works terrifically for what it was designed for, which is to operate in a console-like environment with fixed-width fonts. It was never intended to work with variable-width fonts or graphical rendering. That said, it sure would be terrific if PIL *did* have a wrap or shrink text to fit method :)