# How can I draw text on an image in a subtitle-fashion using PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am looking to transcribe an audio file using PIL. I have already the system in place to transcribe speech from an audio file, and now I need to write each occurrence of speech to a unique image and string them all together to make a video.

I am having some difficulty figuring out how to write text to an image in a "subtitle-like" fashion. The text should be at the bottom of the image, written clearly, and wrapped properly. Essentially, I think the size of the image matters, which might be different for different images (for the purposes of this project, I do not want images to be resized). Therefore, the "placement" of the text is going to matter based on the size of the image - even the fontsize will matter.

Does anyone have any idea? Here is some preliminary code:

```py
def transcribe_image(text: str):
    image = Image.open(os.path.join(IMAGE_DIR, IMAGE_MOON_SEA))
    newimg = Image.new("RGB", image.size)
    newimg.paste(image)

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(newimg)

    font = ImageFont.truetype(font=ARIAL_FONT, size=FONT_SIZE)
    width_image, height_image = image.size[0], image.size[1]

    draw.text((int(FONT_PLACEMENT[0] * width_image), int(FONT_PLACEMENT[1] * height_image)),
              text, fill=(255, 255, 255, 255), font=font)

    temp = tf.NamedTemporaryFile()
    newimg.save(temp.name + ".jpg")
```

I need help figuring out a couple of things. Depending on the `width_image` and `height_image`, what should:

1. FONT_SIZE be?
2. FONT_PLACEMENT be? (This is an array currently set to [0.5, 0.5]
3. How can I assure that text is wrapped properly?

If there is anything else I am missing, or something I can take a look at, please let me know. It's my first time using PIL, so if anyone notices I'm doing something wrong or can be done better, please let me know as well.

Comment: possibly answered elsewhere already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257147/wrap-text-in-pil

Comment: @Abel thank you, I think that this answer is enough to get me started. It is definitely not answering my question, though.

Comment: there are subtitling guidelines all over the nets... some say max 2 lines, etc.

Comment: IMHO this sort of thing is much easier with `wand` https://stackoverflow.com/a/63089810/2836621