# Show a variable as an image

Tags: python, html, image, variables, flask

I am working on a project where I have to display certain variables/counters on a webpage. Rather than using socket.io I want to convert my variable into an image.

By image I mean if the variable was `x = 2;` I need `2` to be converted into an image like this:
[The number 2 in the form of an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6uMK.jpg)

I have already found a way to send image bit by bit to my html page using flask. If I can convert the variable like this then I could easily display it on my webpage.

If anyone could give any ideas it would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: If you already can send the image from Flask to the web page, then you should just need to map the variable value to the corresponding image correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, but for every value I need to display an image of that number, if that makes sense.

Comment: You could use a [JavaScript Canvas](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) to [convert text to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf).

Comment: But how do I tell my JavaScript what the text is. How do I send the text from my flask app to js?

Comment: You can [generate the image in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856242/convert-string-to-image-in-python)

Comment: this might be helpful thankyou so much pidge