# Create variants of a document with corresponding labels for AI training

Tags: vba, machine-learning, ms-word

I am looking for an easy solution for the following problem:
I have to create variants of a document and export them as an image. This could be easily done with the MS Word Mail Merge, but I need the pixel positions of every text block in that document. The image as well as the pixel positions are input for an AI training.

At the moment I can think of several approaches:

1. Throw the MS Word Mail Merge output into an OCR and try to identify the positions of the text blocks by comparing them with the original text source.
2. Create the document with something like JS, Python or Visual Basic and save the exact positions of each inserted text block at the time of inserting.
3. Maybe use Visual Basic for Word to extract the text positions from the MS Word XML file that was created with the Mail Merge function.

Variant 1 seems to be overly complicated because it uses some kind of reverse engineering. Additionally, using an OCR even on a perfectly readible document can always be a source of error.

So variants 2 or 3 seem fine, but I don't know any libraries that fit the requirements and Visual Basic for Word is absolutely new territory for me.

I hope I described the problem well enough. If you want me to clarify something, please let me know.

I appreciate every idea and help! :)

Best Regards
Henrik

Answer (score 0):

Seems like someone already dislikes my post. Please let me know how I can improve before voting me down..

Anyway, I may have found a way to realize variant 2. This [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698231/python-pil-draw-multiline-text-on-image) references a [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/turicas/1455973) that extends the Python Image Library. It offers a function to write text on an image and also set a maximum width for the text box. The function also returns the final width and height of the drawn text box. Using this I will try to implement an algorithm that creates the document images as well as the label files.

Maybe this will also help someone else looking for the same thing.