# How can I tell Pillow what the grids are and how can I fit text in that so it won't exceed the grid-blocks?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to figure out something with the Pillow module. For a bingo-esque thing, I want to lay out a grid of 5x5, and fill that with questions that I have randomly generated in a list. So far so good.

I have figured out how to position stuff in Pillow so it will have text in the middle of the block, but that's done manually. I need to figure out if I can define the specific blocks, so I can make sure text doesn't cross into other blocks.

This is how I've generated the image the attached screenshot shows.

[image]

This is my code so far (I know the input for the fields has quotes around them, this is to make it easier during debugging.)

```
def babbelbingo_file():
    file = gclient.open_by_key("obfuscated")
    babbelbingo = file.get_worksheet(1)
    values =  babbelbingo.get_all_values()
    list_values = [item for sublist in values for item in sublist]
    questions = random.sample(list_values, k=24)
    return questions

def make_bingocard(name, questions):
    image = Image.open('jeevesbot/files/bingokaart.png')
    font_name = ImageFont.truetype('jeevesbot/files/Overpass-regular.ttf', 20)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=25)
    word_list = wrapper.wrap(text=questions[0])
    text_new = ''
    for ii in word_list[:-1]:
        text_new = text_new + ii + '\n'
    text_new += word_list[-1]
    draw.text((140, 275), 'questions[0]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')
    draw.text((274, 275), 'questions[1]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')
    draw.text((408, 275), 'questions[2]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')
    draw.text((542, 275), 'questions[3]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')
    draw.text((676, 275), 'questions[4]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')

    draw.text((140, 394), 'questions[5]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')
    draw.text((274, 394), 'questions[6]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')
    draw.text((408, 394), 'questions[7]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')
    draw.text((542, 394), 'questions[8]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')
    draw.text((676, 394), 'questions[9]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')

    draw.text((140, 513), 'questions[10]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')
    draw.text((274, 513), 'questions[11]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')
    draw.text((542, 513), 'questions[12]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')
    draw.text((676, 513), 'questions[13]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')

    draw.text((140, 632), 'questions[14]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')
    draw.text((274, 632), 'questions[15]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')
    draw.text((408, 632), 'questions[16]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')
    draw.text((542, 632), 'questions[17]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')
    draw.text((676, 632), 'questions[18]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')

    draw.text((140, 751), 'questions[19]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')
    draw.text((274, 751), 'questions[20]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')
    draw.text((408, 751), 'questions[21]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')
    draw.text((542, 751), 'questions[22]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')
    draw.text((676, 751), 'questions[23]', (0, 0, 0), font=font_name, align='left', anchor='mm')
    image.save('jeevesbot/files/generated_bingocards/' + name + '.png')

def bingo(name):
    questions = babbelbingo_file()
    make_bingocard(name, questions)
```

Comment: Have you tried `multiline_text()` ([docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.multiline_text)) at the size of a single square and then horizontally and vertically center the text inside? You can do that with a combination of `align` and `anchor`.

Comment: That would still not get me a way to limit the text to specific coordinates right? I can try to see if it fits my situation, in any case. :)

Comment: Ah, if you also need to wrap text, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7698300/189362

Comment: I'm actually using textwrap, maybe I'm not doing it right; I'll give that SO link a try :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a script that combines the answer linked in my previous comment plus your code to achieve what you're looking for (I think). The key thing in my solution vs. your code is that I'm doing the textwrapping per question rather than once.

```py
import math
import textwrap
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

def get_questions():
    return [
        'this is my first question',
        'a second question that wraps into three lines',
        'third question',
        'this is a very very long question that will wrap a couple of lines because it just wont end'
    ]

def draw_question(image, question, x_offset, y_offset):
    '''
    Based on Franck's answer in python PIL draw multiline text on
    image, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56205095/189362 .

    In this first approach we calculate the amount of lines that we're 
    going to need, calculate the offset from the top, and then draw  
    the text line by line, increasing the offset as we go.
    '''
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    question_width = 300
    question_height = 300
    lines = textwrap.wrap(question, width=20)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 24)
    text_color = (255, 0, 0)

    line_height = font.getsize(lines[0])[1]
    y_text = y_offset + (question_height / 2) - (len(lines) * (line_height / 2))

    for line in lines:
        line_width = font.getsize(line)[0]
        draw.text(
            (
                x_offset + (question_width - line_width) / 2,
                y_text
            ), 
            line,
            font=font,
            fill=text_color
        )
        y_text += line_height

def draw_question_alt_approach(image, question, x_offset, y_offset):
    '''
    Another approach would be to first draw the text in a separate 
    image, calculate its bounding box, and then merge it with our main
    image. Result is the same, just a different approach (with better 
    readable code imho).
    '''
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    question_width = 300
    question_height = 300
    lines = textwrap.wrap(question, width=20)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 24)
    text_color = (255, 0, 0)

    text_img = Image.new('RGBA', (question_width, question_height), (255, 255, 255, 0))
    text_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(text_img)
    text_draw.multiline_text((0, 0), "\n".join(lines), font=font, fill=text_color, align='center')
    bbox = text_img.getbbox()

    x = int(x_offset + (question_width / 2) - math.floor(bbox[2] / 2))
    y = int(y_offset + (question_height / 2) - math.floor(bbox[3] / 2))

    image.alpha_composite(text_img, (x,y))

def draw_card(name, questions):
    image = Image.open('bingokaart.png')
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

    question_positions = [
        [ 0, 0 ],
        [ 300, 0 ],
        [ 0, 300 ],
        [ 300, 300 ],
    ]

    for i, question in enumerate(questions):
        draw_question_alt_approach(image, question, question_positions[i][0], question_positions[i][1])

    image.save('generated_bingocards/' + name + '.png')

def bingo(name):
    questions = get_questions()
    draw_card(name, questions)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bingo('foo')
```

Gives:

[image: bingokaart generated by this code]

Comment: I fixed my code with a not-so-nice looking combination of textwrap and multiline_text; but yours is definitely working and looking great! Thanks for the input!