# Pillow displays Farsi from bottom to top

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

When I use Farsi or Arabic, it displays multi-line text from bottom to top.

```
import os
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
import textwrap


def text_to_image(text, width=300, height=100, background=(0, 0, 0, 0)):
    text = get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(text)).encode().decode('utf-8')

    image = Image.new("RGBA", (width, height), background)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("test_kivy/font/Sahel.ttf", 20, encoding='unic')
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

    word_list = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=30).wrap(text=text)
    text = ''
    for text_new in word_list:
        text += f"{text_new}\n"

    box = draw.textbbox((0, 0), text, font)
    h = box[2] - box[0]
    w = box[3] - box[1]

    draw.text((w-50, 0), text, (0, 0, 0), font=font, align='right')
    image.save(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "Test.png"))
    # image.show()


text_to_image(text='این یک متن فارسی صرفا برای تست است نمایش آن اشتباه از پایین به سمت بالا است.')
```

[image: screenshot]

It should display top to bottom.

Comment: Thank you dear friend
But this is not a good method, at least it should be controlled with a method.

Comment: Sometimes you have to do things by less that the perfect method just to get them done — so I think you should reconsider using the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7698300/355230) I linked.