# Dynamic Text Wrapping in PIL

Tags: python-imaging-library, word-wrap

[enter image description here][1]I am trying to make a program that can layout various lengths of texts in non-rectangular shapes. I'm not seeing any built-in code in PIL, or textwrap That allows for this. Essentially looking for the wrap around image functionality that one would see in word, except, wrap inside the image (shape), making the font size as large as possible.

I'm seeing plenty of solutions to write multiline text as a square, for example this thread: [PIL - draw multiline text on image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698231/pil-draw-multiline-text-on-image).

However I need to fit my text into an uneven polygon, and it seems that every text draw expects a straight line to define the boundries. I am afraid I don't understand enough vector math to reconfigure it to accept angular lines.

Currently using this snippet:

```
img = Image.open("Frames/defaultframe.png")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

selected_size = 1
for size in range(1, 150):
    title = "SOME TITLE HERE"
    titleFont = ImageFont.FreeTypeFont('C:/Windows/Fonts/POORICH.TTF', size=size)
    w, h = titleFont.getsize(title)  # older versions
   
    if w > 300 or h > 45:
        break
        
    selected_size = size
         
titleFont = ImageFont.FreeTypeFont('C:/Windows/Fonts/POORICH.TTF', size=selected_size)

draw.text((435, 135), title, fill='black', anchor='mm', font=titleFont)
```

Adapted from another question, and it works perfect for the small rectable at the top of my image.

The polygon is defined as:
`boundry = draw.polygon(xy=[(130, 405),(642, 405),(625, 537),(580, 660),(285, 660),(200, 550)], fill=(255, 255, 0))`

I would love to be able to loop through font-sizes to find the largest possible while having the lines restrained within the above polygon, just as they are in the square above.

Below is a link to what I'm trying to do: wrap the text inside the yellow polygon
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pynCS.png

Comment: Could you add an example image showing the _polygon_ and the text wrapped as desired? Also code as [example] helps to see how the polygon is drawn. For the text-fitting we need the polygon's boundary coordinates.

Comment: I've adding in what I've been using for rectangles and the shape I'm trying to reproduce the wrapping inside.